# How can I print PHP syntax highlighting on a colour printer?

Tags: printing, gedit, syntax-highlighting

This must have been answered before, but I simply cannot find the answer either here or elsewhere.

I edit a PHP file in `gedit`, which is all nicely coloured for syntax.

But when I want to print it, it prints only in black-and-white.

How can I print it in colour? I will accept an editor other than `gedit` if needed, because of [bug 1313283](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtksourceview3/+bug/1313283).

I'd prefer a GUI option, please, partly because finding my printer's name for the command line is hard, and partly because I don't know how to set my printer's options from the command line (I think that its default mode is black-and-white).

I have discovered `enscript`, but unfortunately it doesn't have PHP highlighting.

**EDIT**

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and `gedit` version 3.10.4.

Comment: Did you try printing it as a pdf and then printing?

Comment: In Gedit you have an option "Print Syntax Highlighting" in the print dialog. Press print and then go to "Text Editor" tab. You should see a "Print Syntax Highlighting" checkbox. Make sure it is switched on if you don't want it printed in black and white.

Comment: @nobody, I found the setting in `gedit`, and it was already on. I retried anyway, but still no colour.

Comment: @Nuwan, yes, I did try, but the PDF is also in black-and-white. It must be bug 1313283 at fault.

Comment: @PaddyLandau here is my test pdf. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbr8lhcc1b27bod/test.php.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @Nuwan What version of Ubuntu and gedit are you using? Mine doesn't do that. When I turn syntax highlighting off, it prints in standard black-and-white as you'd expect. But when I turn it on, the only change is that keywords are in bold (but still black-and-white).

Comment: @PaddyLandau gedit 3.18.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, oh you mean that you can't evan see colors on gedit itself?

Comment: @Nuwan I can see the colours on `gedit`, but as you can see from [bug 1313283](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtksourceview3/+bug/1313283), `gedit` can't print colours. It seems that in your version of `gedit`, which is 8 sub-versions later than mine, the fault has been fixed. I'll try to see if it's possible to backport Ubuntu 16.04's version of `gedit` to 14.04.

Comment: Hmm, `gedit` does not have a backport, unfortunately. So, I'm still looking for a solution. A different editor, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went into one of my PHP files in gedit (Ubuntu 16.04). It does come up nicely color-coded. I then did ^P, selected an HP Photosmart C4100 series printer in the print dialog. All the color-coding printed beautifully. It worked painlessly for me. I hope this helps.

Will that printer print color from another application?

Comment: Good info! So it looks like this must have been fixed for the version of Gedit included in Ubuntu 16.04 -- my guess is that Paddy has an older version of Ubuntu.

Comment: It is not the Ubuntu version. My guess is that this is the setting in Gedit which controls syntax highlighting for printing.

Comment: Where is the gedit setting for printing? I did look for it, but not found. @NickWeinberg, I have edited my question to indicate the versions that I use. EDIT: I found the setting, and it was already on. I retried anyway, but it still doesn't print in colour.

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer, because the answer is essentially to update `gedit` (in this case, I updated Ubuntu to 16.04). Installing `pluma` instead of `gedit` will also do the job.